# Script a microservices (Windows service) deploy in a lean way

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, deployment

My application consist in a bunch of microservices. All microservices are inside a single Visual Studio solution. Each microservice has a Console Application project with Topshelf that is used to easily install the microservice as a Windows service.

Microservices locally developed need to be installed as Windows Service on a server inside our network (same domain). The current process is:

1. Build solution (per environment transformation made with Slow Cheetah)
2. Copy build artifacts from my File Manager
3. Remote desktop to the server
4. Past artifacts in a choosen directory (on the server)
5. install with TopShelf `service.exe install -username:XXX -password:YYY`
6. start the service

If I wrote a bugfix I need to redo the first five step and restart the service.
Consider this job multiplied by number of services, multiplied for new feature. Hell life!

What I'd like is a leaner deploy process. Given that the team is not so good at unit test a *real* continuous integration/delivery strategy is not so feasible. So what I really would is a sort of script that will do the above six steps in automatic manner and ideally:

- the script should be under source control (ideally inside the Topshelf host project)
- the script should be runnable in Visual Studio
- the script should ask in what environment *deploy*

I would avoid complex continuous integration tool like TeamCity (maybe together with Octopus Deploy or other orchestrator), since we have an appropriate code coverage, and I just prefer a replacement for that six steps.

What about Psake? Can someone have some experience in similar issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do everything you want with PowerShell scripts.

I'd parameterise the variables that change per environment using environment variables and a build condition to execute the variable setup script based on Build type (I'm assuming you have at least one build config per environment using SlowCheetah).

Write your PowerShell scripts using those generic environment variables. You will need adminstrator and remote script execution rights to the deployment machines in order to run executables and start/stop services.

Also consider a lighter CI server option like CruiseControl.NET if you can't get a TeamCity installation going. CC.Net includes PowerShell script execution options in the build configurations.

**Script example:**

*PowerShell Copy:*

```
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination
```

*Start service:*

```
start-service $SvcName
```

**Extra links:**

[Tutorial on running remote scripts using PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/use-powershell-invoke-command-to-run-scripts-on-remote-computers/)